# Upgrading SQL Server Express 20008 -> 2012 (Visual Studio)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am running VS 2013 and SQL Server Express 2008 on a Windows 7 32 bit box.

It's a simple setup with 1 database and a couple users.

To upgrade to SQL Express 2012, can I just run the install, will it update everything in place?

Will it impact VS 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SQL 2012 Upgrade Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) first. It won't fix anything for you, but it will give you advice on possible migration issues.

Also run the [Distributed Replay Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878702.aspx) to  measure performance differences and look for any incompatibilities your application(s) may have with the upgrade.

Finally, don't miss the things in this list - [UPGRADING TO SQL 2012: TEN THINGS YOU DON’T WANT TO MISS.](http://thomaslarock.com/2013/03/upgrading-to-sql-2012-ten-things-you-dont-want-to-miss/)

In short, don't expect the upgrade to be just a few clicks and smooth sailing :)